# Replace URLs in wp_postmeta's meta_value relating to specific meta_key

Tags: mysql, wordpress, replace, phpmyadmin

In the wp_postmeta table I would like to replace URLs that occur in the meta_value field (besides other content) but only when certain meta_keys match.

The content of those entries are linked images. The outgoing url should be changed but the path to the image has to remain the same.

Example:

```
<a href="https://olddomain.com/?someparameters" target="_blank" >
<img src="https://olddomain.com/wp-content/..." />
</a>
```

Should become:

```
<a href="https://newdomain.com/?someparameters" target="_blank" >
<img src="https://olddomain.com/wp-content/..." />
</a>
```

my query to get only those rows is:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'sa_slide%_content'
```

If anyone could suggest a query to do this would save me hours and hours of manual labor.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So after some further reading and some trial and error I came up with the sql query myself:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'href="https://olddomain.com/', 'href="https://newdomain.com/')
WHERE meta_value LIKE '%href="https://olddomain.com/%'
AND meta_key LIKE 'sa_slide%_content';
```

So the trick was to only match strings with href to target only the outgoing links and to add the AND condition to only perform the operation in those rows